# multiple select dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, css, yii

I'm using yii dropdownlist and when i add 'multiple' => 'multiple', then block of that dropdown will get disappeared.

My code is below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/prettify.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/prettify.js"></script>

<div class="form-group xtype-sel">
<div class="sel-holder">
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('type', '', $color,  [ 
'empty'=>'Select', 'class'=>'type-sel filter-sel',
'id' => 'xyz', 'multiple' => true   
]); ?>

</div>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#xyz').multiselect();
});
</script>
```

I want checkbox in dropdown (ie. multiselect) but adding checkbox in dropdown , the dropdown block is disappeared from the page but the multiselect dropdown is working perfectly outside this css class(ie. form-group xtype-sel & sel-holder)
but including in this css the block of dropdown is disappeared.

Plz help me regarding how to solve, i'm struggling from last 2 days , thanx in advance.

Comment: what is the error are you getting? Check the browser console and see if there are any error

Comment: in console i have checked i'm not getting any error.

Comment: format of multiple on yii is something like this `'multiple' => 'multiple'` include that where appropriate.

Comment: that also i have tried 'multiple'=>'multiple' but same issue

Comment: try placing it inside `array()` just like the yii docs

Comment: @aysuh in your case like this `<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('type', '', $color, array( 
'empty'=>'Select', 'class'=>'type-sel filter-sel',
'id' => 'xyz', 'multiple' => true   
)); ?>`

Comment: @mike ross just now i tried with array() but same issue is coming

Comment: add some more code in your question including what you have tried and where are you getting $color from and why is your second argument empty?

Comment: i tried this in my project and it worked like a charm, something might be conflicting in your code so insert some more code if possible `<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('listname', '',
  array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'),
  array('empty' => '(Select a gender)','multiple'=>'multiple')); ?>`

Comment: @mike i tried in a sample project it works perfectly

Comment: but the code i mentioned i think some css is blocking the dropdown with multiple select

Comment: look into browser console and see the dropdown css and xyz name. Try to change the `id` of html elements and you may get the results.

Comment: @mike tried all thing but no progress.

Comment: there may be multiple factors affecting this. I would make a new page and insert the external link one by one and check the effect or sometimes order of inserting external links may affect it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93031/discussion-between-ayush-and-mike-ross).

Comment: Why is the [tag:prettify] tag on this question?

Comment: @mike samuel its a javascript library

Comment: @Ayush, Ok.  I removed the prettify tag because the question doesn't relate specifically to that library any more than it does to jquery or bootstrap.